# Hibernate one to many relationship annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity-relationship, hibernate-annotations

I have problem with settings relationship one to many. I want to create relationship between FindingAid and FindingAidVersion. I tried example in Hibernate documentation and many examples in the Internet but I don't know what is wrong.

**FindingAid.java**

```
    Public class FindingAid implements Serializable {
        private String id;
        ....
        @OneToMany
        @JoinColumn(name="id")
        private  Set<FindingAidVersion> listVersion = new HashSet<FindingAidVersion();
         ...... generate getter and setter .....
     }
```

**FindingAidVersion.java**

```
        Public class FindingAidVersion implements Serializable {
          private String id;
          private Date closeDate;
          private FindingAid findingAid;
          .......
          @ManyToOne
          @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
          public FindingAid getFindingAid() {
                return findingAid;
            }
         ...... generate getter and setter .....
        }
```

**Application code is:**

```
    FindingAid data = new FindingAid();
    data.setCreateDate(new Date());
    data.setName("daniel");

    FindingAidVersion verse = new FindingAidVersion();
    verse.setCloseDate(new Date());
    verse.setIsClose(false);


    data.getListVersion().add(verse);
    this.getSession().save(data);

    this.getTx().commit();
```

**Error is:**
 Repeated column in mapping for entity: cz.tacr.elza.api.model.FindingAidVersion column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

I know that problem is in annotation @JoinColumn but I am lost.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: can you add insert="false" update="false" in FindingAidVersion mapping and try it, because error says it.

Comment: The `@OneToMany` shouldn't be accompanied with `@JoinColumn`. Instead, you should use: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "findingAid")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do what the error message suggest ?

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insert=false, update=false)
```

And in FindindAid for the listVersion attribute try

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="findingAid")
```

Look at your new error:

```
 foreign key constraint "fk_3o68boae9f3oamcm6dfy77tfw" cannot be implemented Detail: Key columns "findingaid" and "id" are of incompatible types: bytea and character varying
```

On one table (finding_aid_version ) you have "findingAid bytea" and on the other (finding_aid) "id varchar(255)",

Comment: **I tried your sollution, but now it shows this error:**


`2015-08-06 18:14:11.134 ERROR 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table finding_aid_version add constraint FK_3o68boae9f3oamcm6dfy77tfw foreign key (findingAid) references finding_aid
2015-08-06 18:14:11.135 ERROR 8928 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : ERROR: foreign key constraint "fk_3o68boae9f3oamcm6dfy77tfw" cannot be implemented
  Detail: Key columns "findingaid" and "id" are of incompatible types: bytea and character varying.`

Comment: can you post your db script ?

Comment: `Hibernate: 
    create table finding_aid (
        id varchar(255) not null,
        date_create date not null,
        is_delete boolean,
        name varchar(100) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table finding_aid_version (
        id varchar(255) not null,
        date_close date not null,
        findingAid bytea,
        is_close boolean not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    alter table finding_aid_version 
        add constraint FK_3o68boae9f3oamcm6dfy77tfw 
        foreign key (findingAid) 
        references finding_aid`

Comment: i edited your question. It is easier to read and to see for other people

Comment: I didnt wrote any error. And why did you delete my edition ? it was more readable

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that I have deleted your edition